# should back end service for windows phone push notificatin always be a cloud application?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to develop an application that makes use of MSPN service. Is it necessary that my backend service be a cloud service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There would be no way to determine if a service is a cloud service or not (without being anti-competitive), so you should be able to use any web service, whether it is implemented using a cloud service such as Azure or not - as I understand it, for certification, it would have to be a web service, and not rely on *something* being installed on a PC on a private network.

Answer (score 1):

No you dont need it to be a Cloud-Service, you can even implement your Push-Service in PHP or similar. But that has Limits, it cannot run periodically a Script or sth like that. All Push-Notifications have to be send manually.

To do this you need 2 Core-Components(In my example in PHP).

1. You have a Page on which the Phone-Application can register his MSPN Push-Uri, which then is stored into the Database.
2. A Page which takes the Uri(s) and then sends the Push-Notification to them